# Explicitly set precedence in Django template filters

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to set explicitly set precedence in Django template filters?

Like a sort of brackets system.

I'm trying to say

```
{{ label | default:( parameter | parse_label ) }}
```

A `label` is some human-friendly string like `"Project ID"` and a parameter is more like `"project_id"`.

I want a system where if a label isn't specifically provided, it runs the `parse_label` custom filter which returns a human-friendly version similar to the above - but at the moment, the code I have is running the `parse_label` filter regardless of whether a `label` is provided - presumably because it's doing something like this

```
{{ (label | default:parameter) | parse_label }}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can achieve this with the [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag.

```
{% with param=parameter|parse_label %}
    {{ label | default:param }}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect!